# Magento Upgrade to 1.7

Tags: magento

while trying to upgrade magento using magento connect, after upgrading frontend and backend shows this error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/dressfromeurope.com/avmmaxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php
>   on line 23 anyone can help?

Comment: Magento connect did work for me. This method works for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes

Answer (score 1):

It seems the compiler is turned on, turn it off (cache also) and retry.

If successful, run the compilation process again and enable compilation and cache.

Comment: Issue is fixed now, i installed new magneto, and then place extensions + theme files in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have u done some changes in core file(s) in magento.
Because if some modification is done in core file(s) of magento, it causes problem while upgrading.